# Permanently change video card clock and fan settings

Tags: graphics-card, bios

Like with RivaTuner. I am thinking maybe some kind of prog that can change the video card bios/rom.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[AtiTool](http://www.techpowerup.com/atitool/) looks to be of the right vintage to support your card.  I can't test it here and offer no guarantees, however.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by definition you cannot change the ROM. ROM means Read-Only Memory.

As to permanently changing the videocard's settings, it will probably vary card to card. What video card are you changing?

Comment: an old ati x800 gt. The fan is extremely loud. I want to save some settings to make it quieter.

Answer (score 0):

> an old ati x800 gt. The fan is extremely loud. I want to save some settings to make it quieter.

Well if the fan is loud, have you tried cleaning the fan and its intake/output ports? Are you sure that its just not a loose/broken bearing, as these can get quite loud?

Either way, I would highly recommend not forcing the fan to go slower unless you have another dedicated fan or liquid cooling that you can use. Doing so may just fry the card

Comment: If you clean the fan using "canned air" be careful that you do not let the fan spin freely in the airstream (technically, the alcohol stream) as this could damage the fan and motor. Hold the fan blades gently just to keep them from spinning freely as you blow. This will clean the blades without damaging the fan.